# Rotate UIView according to iDevice Magnetometer reading

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cgaffinetransform, magnetometer

I have a `UIView` containing some points within, and I make it rotate according to the readings from magnetometer via `CLLocationManager`, as follow:

```
@interface PresentationVC () {
    float initialBearing;
}
@end

@implementation PresentationVC
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
#pragma mark - CLLocationManager Delegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
    if(initialBearing == 0) {
        initialBearing = newHeading.magneticHeading;
    }
    NSLog(@"Magnetic Heading: %f", newHeading.magneticHeading);
    viewMap.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(initialBearing - newHeading.magneticHeading));
}

@end
```

where `viewMap` is the `UIView`.

The above code works, but I want the transform of `UIView` set to 0 degree / radian, which is `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)`. Currently it sets to current bearing initially, which is, for example, 157 degree.

I try to use `initialBearing` in the above code to calculate the offset angle, but it still rotates to an angle initially. What did I miss?

Also, I can't rotate a full 360 degree; the `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` bounces back the rotation when I turn almost 180 degree instead. How can I rotate a full 360 degree rotation without bouncing? (I guess it's about radian degree issue)

Comment: seems to be ok, here is your code and it's working fine ("red" view) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19438780/testHeading.zip

Comment: Really thanks for your demo project! End up it's my `degreeToRadians()` malfunctioning. See my answer below!

Answer (score 1):

End up I found that the `degreeToRadians()` is malfunctioning, making the radian calculation incorrect.

```
// this is malfunctioned
#define degreesToRadians(degrees) (M_PI * degrees / 180.0)

// this is working, thanks @TonyMkenu
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```